# How to get current `coroutineContext` from a non-suspend function?

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines, kotlin-coroutines

Say I have a logging function:

```
fun log(message: String)
```

Unfortunately, this function will be called both from coroutines and outside of coroutines. In case of coroutines, I would like to log additional information coming from coroutine context (for example, coroutine's name).

How can I achieve this?

These are my thoughts but I don't have a solution:

- Somehow figure out inside `log` if it is inside a coroutine and get `coroutineContext`. Is this possible?
- I could have two versions of `log` e.g. `log` and `logSuspend`. But how do I ensure the right one gets called? If I'm inside `suspend`, nothing prevents me from calling `log` by accident. Additionally, I may have a regular helper function. Which one should it call?
- Maybe something with `ThreadLocal`, for example I could `coroutineContext` inside a `ThreadLocal` at some point, but how do I ensure it stays up to date?

Answer (score 1):

> Somehow figure out inside log if it is inside a coroutine and get
>   coroutineContext. Is this possible?

I don't think there is a good solution for that.

I would create two `log` functions, first for general purpose, second - an extension function on `CoroutineScope` for coroutines:

```
fun log(message: String) {...}

fun CoroutineScope.log(message: String) {
    //here you can access coroutineContext
}
```

And if you call `log` function from the coroutine like this:

```
GlobalScope.launch {
    log("CoroutineScope.log")
}
```

the extension function will be called and you will have access to **coroutineContext**.

**Note:** **GlobalScope** is not recommended to use, it is just for demonstration purposes.